# How much do we know about the Second Apostolic Council of Jerusalem of 69 AD?

Tags: council-of-jerusalem

How much do we know about the Second Apostolic Council of Jerusalem of 69 AD?

I just bumped into a source that claims that Irenaeus, Eusebius and Saint Clement of Rome all mentioned that council. Is it that meeting that took place when Paul came back to Jerusalem in the book of Acts 21:18:

> And the day following Paul went in with us unto James; and all the
>   elders were present. (KJV)

or is it a council that took place much later? (I don't know the year when Paul returned to Jerusalem)

How much do we know about that council, what decisions were made?

Wikipedia has no article on the Second Apostolic Council of Jerusalem of 69 AD.

Comment: It sounds like the "first apostolic council of Jerusalem" might have been the one in acts 21. It would be great to know what history tells us about both of these.

Comment: @disciple - Then the one in Acts 15 must be the "zero apostolic council of Jerusalem"  :)

Comment: Can you reference the quotes from the sources claimed about the so-called council?  Lots of myth out there.

Answer (score 3):

The end of Acts leaves us with Paul under house arrest, waiting to see Caesar, but he was later brought before Nero, who died in the year 68 AD, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero). It is generally reckoned that Paul was executed by Nero, so Paul, also, would have departed this life on or before that same year.

So it would seem unlikely, or even impossible, that the incident in Acts 21:18 refers to 69 AD.

Comment: about "waiting to see the Emperor Augutus". [Augustus died AD 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus) so it must have been someone else. If it was the one who preceded Nero then maybe it was [Claudius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudius)

Comment: @x457812 Yes, quite right. My mistake. Edited.